# How to include an include tag parameter as value of an iterator tag in struts2

Tags: struts2

I have a jsp *to_include.jsp* that i wanna include in another one using the < s:include > tag passing a string parameter. Here is the code of the including jsp:

```
<div>
    <s:include value="to_include.jsp">
        <s:param name="list">list_of_objects</s:param>
    </s:include>
</div>
```

That *list* param is the name of an array object that is iterated inside the included jsp. I can easily access the list name in the include jsp using:

```
<%= request.getParameter("list") %>
```

But in the < s:iterator > attribute *value* you can't include expression inside tags like the one just showed. My question is, how can i access the *list* parameter inside the iterator tag?

```
<s:iterator value="?">
    ...
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead, use the s:set tag to take an action property and set it to a value on the value stack which the included page can then access.

Comment: But i will use to_include.jsp in several jsps. Some of them calling it more than once and from differentes actions. I need to set the list parameter in every < s:include > tag.

Comment: Basically, my problem is how to access the request parameters inside a struts2 tag.

Comment: @DanielCalderon What's the difference? Params are just that--HTTP params, not objects. If you want to pass a list, keep it in the value stack.

Comment: I understand and list_of_object IS in the value stack. I can access to it inside the included jsp if I put the exact name of the list. The problem is to access the name specified in the param list inside the included jsp.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to have the list that is being iterated to be determined by a request parameter, then why not have the selection occur in the action instead of the jsp?

For instance:

```
public class ListAction {

    private List<?> list;
    private ListService listService;

    public String execute() {
        return "success";
    }

    public void setListName(String listName) {
        list = listService.getList(listName);
    }

    public void setListService(ListService listService) {
        this.listService = listService;
    }

    public List<?> getList() {
        return list;
    }

}
```